# Prove that $e^{tQ}$ is a transition matrix for all $t\ge 0$ if $Q$ is a transition rate matrix on a finite set $I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

This is Theorem 2.1.2 of Norris's book on Markov Chains. It can be shown that $$\sum\limits_{k\in I} q_{ik}^{(n)}=0$$ for any n in $N^+$ by conduction, so that$$\sum\limits_{k\in I} p_{ik}(t)=\sum\limits_{k\in I} p_{ik}(0)=1$$ But I'm confused with the proof for $$P(t)\ge 0$$Norris writes that $q_{ij}\ge 0$ for all $ i\ne j$ if and only if $p_{ij}(t)\ge 0$ for all $i\ne j$ and $t\ge 0$ sufficiently small, but I can't see this if $q_{ij}=0$ for some $i,j$.

Comment: *"I can't see this if $_{i,j}=0$ for some ,"* as I mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084373/nice-applications-of-lie-product-formula/4084648 this becomes obvious if you interpret it via the Lie Product Formula -- which pays dividends elsewhere in math.

Comment: Thank you so much!